Uncaught Error: Class "Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient" not found
We are using PHP and NOT composer. We went to https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client?tab=readme-ov-file#download-the-release and downloaded the full release for PHP 8.2 but when we call the below code we get the error "Uncaught Error: Class "Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient" not found" when trying to create the new StorageClient class. Is there something we are missing in our file uploads that the StorageClient is not in the full download without using composer?
require_once '/home/stubwire/public_html/googleapi/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

// Initialize Storage Client
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'projectId' => 'project-testing',
    'keyFilePath' => '/home/domain/public_html/googleapi/key/testing-43987e5aa108.json'
]);

Should create the class object

The library you linked to is not for the Cloud api its for the client stuff (Drive, gmail etc). The StorageClient is part of this package: https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-storage/latest

I was unfamiliar with what composer was and realized that the server did need software installed on it to handle this.
